# High level data structures in html data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am happy that the [html5 data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) exists.

I can write a simple string into html attributes and access them via jquery.

But .... wouldn't it be nice to have more than a simple string?

Is there no way to encode JSON into these data attributes.

In my current use case I need to store a list of strings in a html5 data attribute.

Comment: You can't nest this list some other way in your JavaScript? It's not very good separation of concerns...

Comment: You mean like.... `$("#ele").attr('data-example', JSON.stringify(new Array('1', '2')))`?

Comment: wouldnt a json string work? Like a JSON.Stringify(Object).

Answer (score 1):

```
   <div id ="test" data-something='{"something":"something"}'></div>
```

string in the data-attribute is automatically converted to a JavaScript object.

you can access this in javascript like this.

```
var somethingObject = $("#test").data("something");

var jsonSomethingObject = JSON.stringify(somethingObject);

console.log(somethingObject); //this will print the main javascript object
console.log(jsonSomethingObject);// this will print stringify javascript object
```

you can refer the snippet for same

```js
var someObject = $("#test").data("student");
    
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(someObject);
 
 $('#display').text("id:"+someObject.id +" name:"+someObject.name)
console.log(someObject);
console.log(jsonData);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test" data-student='{"name": "Dhiraj", "id": 1}' />

<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please show me how I can access this dictionary from jquery. Up to now I thought I get a simple string.

Comment: see updated answer to you question in comment

Answer (score 0):

You can put json as string in `data` attribute and use `JSON.parse()` to get it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can use `JSON.stringify`

```js
$("#ele").attr('data-example', JSON.stringify(new Array('1', '2')));

console.log($("#ele").attr('data-example'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='ele' data-example="nothing"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store JSON strings in `data-` attributes.

```js
function onPClick(evt) {
  var special = evt.target.getAttribute('data-special');
  if (special != null) {
    try {
      console.log("JSON", JSON.parse(special));
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("STANDARD", special);
    }
  } else {
    console.log("NULL");
  }
}
var ps = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
for (var pi = 0; pi < ps.length; pi++) {
  var p = ps[pi];
  p.onclick = onPClick;
}
```

```html
<p>I am special!</p>
<p data-special='YES!'>I am special!</p>
<p data-special='{"a":"bob"}'>I am special!</p>
```

For separation of concerns, it would be prettier to hold you data in a place that doesn't have to update the HTML every time it changes:

```js
var p = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("p"));
p.innerHTML = "Click me!";
Object.defineProperty(p, 'mySuperSecretValue', {
  value: 37,
  writable: true,
  enumerable: true,
  configurable: true
});
p.onclick = function pclick(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.mySuperSecretValue++, evt.target.outerHTML);
};
```